# What is the difference between updating the Manifest file manually or using chrome appcache-internals?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a web application that requires a manifest file. There is an issue that causes the chrome browser to hang. This issue only happens in this scenario:

1. I go to the index.html page and let chrome fetch the manifest files
2. I update the manifest header manually and refresh the page to force chrome to get it again
3. Chrome starts getting files but hangs after a while

I thought my issue might be related to manifest but it's funny that if I go to chrome://appcache-internals/ and remove the manifest file from there, the app will be booted without any problem. Is there any differences between these 2 way of forcing chrome to get manifest? 
maybe it can give me some hints to find my problem.
By the way, not only that tab but also the developer tools on that tabs hangs, so I won't be able to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately [AppCache is a douchebag](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag).

Answer (score 0):

Although, AppCache has been criticized a lot and for good reasons, your issue might not be unsolvable. A lot of things can break cached files update by the appcache.

- Some of the paths to your files are incorrect, if so, file fetching will hang/break
- You did not respect AppCache Conventions for you manifest file. Lots of pointers [here](http://appcache.offline.technology/)
- Some other thing has gone awry, then you'll need to do some digging.

So for me, the issue of not fetching all the files might simply be that when you drop the file manually from the tools you force chrome to get it for the first time.